How to convert a JSON containing a SafeOperation into an EthSafeOperation object?
I have the following use case using the Safe SDK and API kits (we are using the Safe4337Pack):

A mobile client sends a transaction request to our backend.
The backend creates the SafeOperation and sends the safeTxHash to the mobile to sign.
The mobile signs the safeTxHash and sends the signature to the BE.
The BE stores the signature
Gather other off-chain signatures following the same process....
Once the threshold is met (we calculate that in the BE), we construct the SafeOperation and add all of the off-chain signatures into the signatures map.
We do this in order to eventually use apiKit.addSafeOperation() that expects a SafeOperation

To construct the SafeOperation (in step 6), we have a JSON with a EthSafeOperation, like the following:
EthSafeOperation {
        signatures: Map(0) {
        },
        chainId: 11155111n,
          moduleAddress: 'Ox...',
          data: {
            safe: 'Ox...',
              nonce: 2n,
              initCode: '0x',
              callData: 'Ox...',
              callGasLimit: 133551n,
              verificationGasLimit: 109930n,
              preVerificationGas: 671n,
              maxFeePerGas: 2443966n,
              maxPriorityFeePerGas: 48707n,
              paymasterAndData: '0x',
              validAfter: 0,
              validUntil: 0,
              entryPoint: 'Ox...'
        }
    }

Is there a way for converting this JSON into an EthSafeOperation?
The one defined in the relay-kit.

What are you trying to achieve? Chances are you don't need to convert it manually but can pass it to the different SDK kits. Would be interested in having a bit more info on what you are trying to do here. Thank you in advance  Best, Louis

Hey there @Louis-SafeCoreTeam!
I have added context in my original question... Looking forward to your reply!

EthSafeOperation implements the class SafeOperation. So you should be able to simply pass it to apiKit.addSafeOperation(). However, since you got a JSON file, the methods associated with the class are no longer available. If you can avoid converting it to JSON and preserve the prototype it would solve the problem.
If this is not possible, we will have to reconstruct the SafeOperation like so (where ethSafeOpJson is your JSON object):
import { AddSafeOperationProps } from '@safe-global/api-kit'
import { UserOperation } from '@safe-global/types-kit'

const userOperation: UserOperation = {
  sender: '0x...',
  signature: '0x...', // Concatenation of all signatures
  ...ethSafeOpJson.data
}

const config: AddSafeOperationProps = {
  entryPoint: ethSafeOpJson.data.entryPoint,
  moduleAddress: ethSafeOpJson.moduleAddress,
  safeAddress: ethSafeOpJson.data.safe,
  userOperation
}

await apiKit.addSafeOperation(config)


Feel free to mark the question as solved if it answered the problem. If not, please let me know!
Thanks in advance  Best, Louis
